# How to redirect a sub-directory to root directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, proxy

I have a wordpress installation.

I want to serve the while site from the sub-directory /swiss/ besides the root directory.
so i'll have 2 ways to access the whole site: the root directory and the swiss directory.

so i want the page /swiss/program/1 to show the page content for /program/1

I want the whole site to work also from the sub-directory /swiss/
so the page https://example.com/sometext will also be accessible from https://example.com/swiss/sometext
so, the 2 URLs will show the same page content.

I tried these rules but it didn't work

```
RewriteRule ^swiss/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^swiss/(.*)$ /$1 [P]
```

I need to insert it in wordpress htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Please be more clear about what your actual physical file system layout is (your DOCUMENT_ROOT's content) and what the URL to access that content should be.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please, recheck the question again.

Comment: Although using an internal proxy request is pretty slow (an extra request for every request...) it should work. The second one you posted should be preferred, obviously. If it "didn't work" then the question is: what does that mean? What happened? What do you see in your http server's error log file? Where did you implement those rules? And how did you make sure that they are considered by the http server _at all_ ?

Comment: it worked with out parameter after slah. but id doesn't work for such url: https://www.example.ch/swiss/programs/dba-in-supply-chain-management/ 
i tried something like RewriteRule ^swiss/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 
but it didn't worked also
@arkascha